# How to check if a page is using vue.js without vue-devtools

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I can check if the page is running angular or angular.js by checking `window.ng` and `window.angullar`.

Is there any such way to check if the page is using vue from the console, without using `vue-devtools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caution! This will work only if the site you're checking has `Vue` as global.**

Open Console of your Browser and Write `Vue`, and after that you will see output like this. *Remember that in Vue, v is in upper case*
[image: ScreenShot of Console]

Comment: this *may* work, but isn't guaranteed at all - none of my Vue sites have `Vue` as a global

Comment: Also, when `Vue` is exposed as a global ... it don't look like that **at all** - but then, I don't put developer version of Vue in production

Answer (score 0):

**Look for Vue in HTML Source Code:**

View the page's HTML source code and search for script tags referencing Vue.js, such as `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

**There are a couple of ways that you can try to check if the website uses `Vue.js` without vue-devtools**

**Check the page's source code**

- Look for references/library imports to Vue.js in the HTML, JS or CSS files containing `vue` keyword.

**Inspect the DOM**

- You can search in the HTML for keywords like `v-`, `data-v-`.

**Check the browser console**

- Open the browser console and check for debug messages referenced to Vue.js